# Increase the row width, column header text color and Caption text size of JQGRID

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatables, jqgrid

I have written a code which will fetch the data from db and display in JQGRID table.

I want to increase the rowwidth of each column in the jqgrid.
How can I do that?

Is there a function to do that?
Also I want to change the text color of the Column header.
I want the text color of column in white and its background in blue.

So basically I want to do following things:

1. Increase/Change the row-width of each column in JQgrid.
2. Change the text color of Column header.
3. Change the text size of JQgrid caption I want it to be slightly bigger then usual.

Comment: its as easy as playing with css. find the class related to the row. override that class to give it some width =)

Comment: Thanks @ecKO but how do I find the class of row in jqgrid. I am new to this so I am not sure

Comment: @RajeshKrishna: Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Additionally, you wrote about "row-width of each column". Do you mean just the width of specific columns or to increase the width of *all* columns proportionally to initial width of columns or based of the width of contents of columns? Do you use `width` property in `colModel` or you really need to change the width *dynamically*?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer thanks for the response.

I found this answer myself:)

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot>td, .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup>td, .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow>td {
    padding: 10px 2px 10px 2px;

}
```